# Length of Django queryset result changes when coerced to a list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a reasonably complex queryset thus, which rolls up data by isoweek:

```
>>> MyThing.objects.all().count()
30000

>>> qs = MyThing.objects.all().order_by('date').annotate(
    dw=DateWeek('date'), # uses WEEK function
    dy=ExtractYear('date')
).values(
    'dy','dw','group_id'
).annotate(
    sum_count=Sum('count')
).values_list('dw', 'dy', 'group_id', 'sum_count')

>>> qs.count()
2000
```

So far so good. The problem is when I coerce this queryset into a list:

```
>>> len(list(qs))
30000
```

Why is this happening? How can I get the list of grouped values that the queryset purports to have when I `count()` it directly?

Comment: What does the coerced list look like? Can you show a few items? `list(qs)[:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, remove the `.order_by('date')`. Although it is not included in the output, the database backend is still considering it at every row, causing the number of rows to inflate like that.

If you want to order the output, `.order_by('dy', 'dw')` after adding those annotations.

You can also add an `.order_by()` with no arguments to clear any ordering set previously, for instance from the Model class definition default ordering.

The reason for this behavior is explained in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> Any fields used in an `order_by()` call are included in the `SQL SELECT`
>   columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in
>   conjunction with `distinct()`. If you order by fields from a related
>   model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may
>   make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra
>   columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to
>   support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are
>   being returned.
>
> Similarly, if you use a `values()` query to restrict the columns
>   selected, the columns used in any `order_by()` (or default model
>   ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the
>   results.
>
> The moral here is that if you are using `distinct()` be careful about
>   ordering by related models. Similarly, when using `distinct()` and
>   `values()` together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the
>   `values()` call.

Comment: Why would that change the length from 30000 to 2000?

Comment: 2000 is the expected length of the output after the group_by, however it's not working properly due to the inclusion of `date` in the ordering.

Comment: I understand. It's mentioned in the docs as well. Note that you can also add an empty `order_by()` to clear any ordering set in the Model.Meta class.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by